# Accessing Text File From one Application to another Application?

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider

I have two Applications named as Application A and Application B.

In Application A, I have one Text File and I wanted to use this File in Application B.
So Is there any way in Android How to use one Text File from one Application to another Application ?

Suggest me some good ways :-)

Comment: if You are storing it in internal package of your application then it is not possible to access it. Otherwise if you are storing it on outside the application package then you can access it using the same file path you have used in the application A.

Comment: But Let me think if the TextFile should placed in Asset Folder what we do for Database,audio files etc then what is the way in Android to use that same File in another Application ?? Can Content Provider will help me ? and How can I do this with use of Content Provider ?

Comment: You may use `ContentProvider` component to access it. I haven't use ContentProvider till now. So dont know how to use it.